# missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, celery

пишу задачу для celory на ping всех датчиков, при получении их статуса, записываю его в базу данных, если датчик не ping, то присваиваю статус 'down'
при запуске celery -A On_OFF_sensor beat -l info
получаю ошибку

> celery.beat.SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task каждую
> минуту: ping_sensor() missing 2 required positional arguments:
> 'ip_sensor' and 'status_sensor'

не могу понять, куда мне передать эти 2 аргумента

вот task.py

```
     @app.task
def ping_sensor(ip_sensor, status_sensor):
    # Проверка доступности датчика
    for sensor in Sensor.objects.all():
        if ping(ip_sensor):
            # sensor = get_object_or_404(Sensor, ip_sensor=ip_sensor)
            sensor.status_sensor = status_sensor
            sensor.save(update_fields=["status_sensor"])
            
        else:
            # Датчик надоступен по пингу записываем его статус в базу данных
            sensor = Sensor.objects.get(ip_sensor=ip_sensor)
            sensor.status_sensor = 'down'
            sensor.save(update_fields=["status_sensor"])
```

я избавился от ошибки. при таске нельзя добавлять в функцию аргументы, их нужно передать через значение из таблицы. вместо ip_sensor пишу sensor.ip_sensor

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Home(models.Model):
    name_home = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descriptions_home = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_home


class Location(models.Model):
    name_location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descriptions_location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    home = models.ForeignKey(Home, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='home')
    guest = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True)  # Чтобы можно было не указывать пользователя

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name_location} ({self.home.name_home})'  # Чтобы отображался еще и Home


class Sensor(models.Model):
    ip_sensor = models.GenericIPAddressField(unique=True, protocol='IPv4')
    name_sensor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descriptions_sensor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='location')
    status_sensor = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

обновленный tasks.py

```
from On_OFF_sensor.celery import app
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from ping3 import ping
import requests
from .models import Sensor
from django.http import JsonResponse


@app.task
def ping_sensor():
    # Проверка доступности датчика
    for sensor in Sensor.objects.all(): #для всех датчиков в Sensor
        if ping(sensor.ip_sensor): #если датчик пинг
            sensor = Sensor.objects.get(ip_sensor=sensor.ip_sensor) #находим датчик по ip
            # sensor.status_sensor = sensor.status_sensor #получаем его статус
            sensor.save(update_fields=["status_sensor"]) #записываем стату в базу данных
            

        else: # Датчик не доступен по пингу
            sensor = Sensor.objects.get(ip_sensor=sensor.ip_sensor) #находим датчик по ip
            sensor.status_sensor = 'down' #присваиваем статус 'down'
            sensor.save(update_fields=["status_sensor"]) #записываем стату в базу данных
```

Comment: передать нужно их там, где вызывается эта функция. Т.е. где-то за пределами этого кода

Comment: Визуально мне не нравится это `for sensor in Sensor.objects.all():` Метод `all` обычно служит для проверки, что все элементы коллекции `True`, а чтобы получить элементы обычно используется метод `items`. Это что за объекты, из какой библиотеки? Или это ваша библиотека и ваши методы?

Comment: в модели у меня есть таблица Sensor в ней есть Ip сенсора и его status. вот я для всех сенсоров (что бы пройтись по всему что есть в таблице) смотрю ping ли датчик. если нет то в базу пишу down? если да, то обновляю таблицу по статусу (еще нужно дописать , что вписать)